# Why do people close down questions because the answer is opinion based? Are not all answers about religion opinion based?

Tags: discussion

You can quote sources, but when it comes to religion all answers are opinion based and not everyone agrees with everybody else on everything.

So why do bruised reed, Nigel J, Kris, Matt Gutting, and curiousdannii feel the need to block my questions because they don't like the answers it might receive?

Comment: If anything, your question is a Meta post. "Opinion based" has a particular meaning on this website. The questions are not closed for reasons of personal preference. But in a nutshell, if you are looking for fellow Christians to answer your questions then you are better off leaving this secular, stiff and formal website for a community of people of faith.

Comment: As long as I know, about opinion based is when one answering the question without a backup which is an existing written opinion comes from the "guru". So, for example _"According to the bible what is necessary to be saved while being sufficient"_, I think should be : _"According to the opinion of denomination X about the Bible, what is necessary to be saved while being sufficient_". With a question like that, one can answer it with a supporting text which is an opinion from the "guru" of denomination X.

Comment: Take a look at how highly upvoted questions are framed. They ask a direct question of a specific denomination. This is not a discussion forum. This question will be migrated to our meta site. Did you notice my edits to your question https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/74262/23657  you could ask the same question again and again each time specifying a different denominational point of view.

Comment: Shouldn't all questions be closed if they don't follow the required format "what does x denomination believe y verse teach regarding z doctrine"? Why are some questions allowed to turn into discussions? Eg: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/73971/does-the-parable-of-the-unforgiving-servant-have-implications-re-once-saved-a

Comment: @ig-dev -- there are facts and logic  versus opinions.   How can anything related to religion not just be opinion.

Comment: @Kris  -  I have no interest in a special denomination and do not have time to repost the same question several hundred times.  I appreciate answers from anyone if they back up their OPINIONS with some reason or citation that shows why they hold that opinion.

Comment: @Seeker -  That would make the site very hard to use.  Also very less useful and dull too.

Comment: @edwinaoliver every new user here goes through the same issues. I certainly did. But the rules of the site are in place for a reason and if you want to participate it will be within those set of rules. You can ask for an overview of Christian beliefs on a topic but this requires an answer that covers multiple denominations.  Most folks here prefer to answer from the one perspective they are most familiar with.

Comment: @edwinaoliver It's opinion whether Mary was sinless, but it's fact whether the Catholic Church teaches that. Make sense?

Comment: It took be patience to stay being a member of this site.

Comment: I have seen other questions allowed for discussion, that did not specify a denomination.

Comment: @FaithMendel It all depends on the question being asked.

Comment: Yea.. And they are the one who determine that my question must need denominational specs right?

Comment: As a mathematician I know how to prove things and know they are correct. There is NO way to do that with religion.  All you can do is have a belief/opinion that may or may not be reasonable and supported by something BUT logically you did not PROVE anything and only have an OPINION in this area of stackexchange.

Comment: @Edwina It's very easy to prove things about religion. This site is all about the questions about Christianity that can be proved, chiefly by explaining the published teachings of Christian denominations or theologians.

Comment: @curiousdanni -  you can prove some things about certain brand names that document what they believe.  But you cannot prove anything about claims of stuff they believe other than that.   Proof by  wishing it were so only works in a few philosophy classes  but fails totally in all math departments.

Answer (score 9):

The stack exchange model is not designed to provide a discussion forum for matters of opinion. It seeks to provide verifiable correct answers to questions within particular topics.  This means that not all questions work well with this particular model.

In order to have a verifiable correct answer for a topic that overall would attract a wide variety of opinions - such as Christianity - it is necessary to scope questions to somehow match a particular identifiable viewpoint.

Some good examples of how to do this can be found amongst our open upvoted questions on the main site, and discussion on the theory and practice of writing such questions are available here on the Meta site, particularly among the relevant [FAQ](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)s.

Comment: Isn't Wikipedia already providing information of : "what does x denomination believe y verse teaches regarding z doctrine"

Comment: @Seeker Sometimes, but it's not usually quite that specific.

Comment: @bruised reed -  One can not provide verified correct answers when it comes to religion.  All one can do is provide their OPINION  and give the reasons that they hold it.  But there are NO facts and logic that prove anything about religion.  It is all faith.

Comment: @edwinaoliver there are facts that state religion x believes y about subject z. You and I may not agree but it is a fact that religion x believes y

Comment: @Kris - lots of people believe a lot of stuff.  Believing something does not make it true.  So, WHY does brand X (or Y or Z) feel the need to put so many things in their list of what they believe if those things are not necessary for salvation.  And if they truly believe you have to believe all the stuff they claim is true then how do we pick which brand name could be the real deal when they all contradict each other so much.

Comment: @edwinaoliver  yes they all contradict which is why asking one question per denomination is the only way to get order on a site like this.

Comment: @Kris  -  I know that.  I want answers from any or all brand names that will answer without posting the question hundreds of times and missing brands that I do not even know of.

Comment: Then start your own site with your own rules

Comment: @edwinaoliver Or start with a question about one 'brand name" church (whatever "brand name" means) and get an answer for that. Maybe that will clear up the issue.

Answer (score 8):

**Why do people close down questions because the answer is opinion based? Are not all answers are opinion based?**

First off, not all questions are opinion based. Some have a very clear definition requirement; some have a very clear, yet difficult yes or no to be sought out with specific doctrines used as supportive evidence. Others require the answer to contain what is (officially) taught by a specific church or denomination.

One should not answer a question simply with their own opinion if evidence to support the answer is simply lacking.

For example: [Is there Catholic teaching and/or prophecy that a pope may be the false prophet of Revelation and the Church the whore of Babylon?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/33368/25495) This question asks for a response that invokes Catholic doctrine, teachings or other sources of proof. One can not simply state an answer based one one’s opinion or even the teachings of another denomination as this could be construed as harming the OP’s original intention. Your answer to this question shows no teachings or other sources from the Catholic Church in this subject matter and is really an unsupported opinion based response lacking Catholic sources.

Generally speaking, we prefer longer answers that are well documented to support one’s response.

[How do I write a good answer?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) from the help centre may be of some help in aiding you to put together a good answer in the near future. Good luck and I hope this helps.

Not all questions about religion are opinion based. The classic joke proves this otherwise: **Is the pope Catholic?**

Comment: Are not all answers ".opinion based??

Answer (score 1):

> ... when it comes to religion all answers are opinion based ...

Not so.

Yes, there will be many who express their opinions and some of that many will be blatantly illogical in their expression of what they have dreamed up.

But true religion is not a matter of opinion for God himself has revealed himself and what he has revealed is the truth.

In amongst all the nonsense, the theories, the fantasies - if one searches it out - there are some who have really, genuinely, truly discovered the living God for themselves. And what they utter is worth hearing.

So this site examines the broad spectrum of what terms itself 'Christianity'. And by comparing the various factions and their articles of faith, it is possible to discover where fantasy ends and where reality begins.

But it is a lifetime's enquiry : requiring patience, diligence, application and devotion.

> Seek - and ye shall find . . . . . [Matthew 7:7, KJV.]

Comment: Ironically, you've invoked an opinion ("true religion is not a matter of opinion") in defending your stand that not all religious questions invoke opinion.

Comment: @Flimzy  Not so. I have given sound evidence supporting the truth of my statement.

Comment: Absolutely So!  Logic shows how things are proven.  You start with facts and use logic to verify a claim.  In this area of stack exchange you can NOT do that and all you have is opinion.

Comment: @edwinaoliver Faith is not opinion. Faith is the awareness of Divine revelation. But not all have faith. For some are not cognizant of the revelation.

Comment: @Nigel J  -  I have faith but that proves nothing.   Facts and logic determine proven truth.  Things may be true without being provable and that is what most religion questions and answers are akin to.

Comment: @edwinaoliver The proof of religion is to know God. One's faith is proved by finding the presence of the only true God. And that proof will be eternal.

Comment: @Nigel J - Faith is not a proof.  It is a belief. That is the same as an opinion.  You may or may not be correct.  But it is NOT PROOF as the bullies on stack exchange demand for questions before they downrate  you and the questions.

Comment: _Faith is the substance of things hoped for : the evidence of things not seen._ Hebrews 11:1.

Comment: @ Nigel- you just showed that I am correct!`  Hope is not proof.

Comment: @edwinaoliver The important words are 'substance' and 'evidence'.

Comment: @Nigel J -  what is evidence for a jury is not sufficient to use with logic for a proof.  It may be true but it is not adequate to prove anything logically,  only by faith.

Comment: 'beyond reasonable doubt' is how juries work.